# If v ∈ R^n is a nonzero vector, and I ∈ R^n×n is an identify matrix. Prove that M = I − 2(v(v^T)/||v||^2 is symmetric and satisfies M^−1 = M

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, symmetric-matrices

I thought about showing M = M^T, so M is symmetric. But I don't know how to compute 2(v(v^T)/||v||^2 to find M and M^T. Any idea?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prove it is symmetric just compute the transpose using the well known properties $(A+B)^T=A^T+B^T$ and $(\lambda A)^T=\lambda A^T$. It should not be a problem.

As for the second part, just multiply $M$ by itself and prove you get the identity matrix. Remember that $v^Tv=\langle v,v\rangle=||v||^2$, you will have to use that.

Comment: So far I have this https://imgur.com/a/sKQHEot, am I correct?

Comment: You have one mistake there. It is false to say that $(vv^T)^T=v^Tv$. Another rule with transposes is that $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$. So in your case it should be $(vv^T)^T=(v^T)^Tv^T=vv^T$. From there you can get the right answer. And by the way, remember that $v^Tv\ne vv^T$ (these are matrices of different orders) so the fact you got $v^Tv$ in the end already should tell you something is wrong.

Comment: Alright I got it, but I don't know how to multiply M by itself for the second part.

Comment: Do I just use the fact that (M^-1)(M^T)= I and M=M^T, so (M^-1)M = I?

Comment: No, just multiply $M$ by itself. You get $(I-2\frac{vv^T}{||v||^2})((I-2\frac{vv^T}{||v||^2})=I-4\frac{vv^T}{||v||^2}+4\frac{v(v^Tv)v^T}{||v||^4}$. And now just use the fact that $v^Tv=\langle v,v\rangle=||v||^2$ and finish from there.

Comment: Why is the last term not 4(vv^T)^2/llvll^4 ? And can you explain a bit more on why M^2 = I implies M = M^-1? Because M.M^-1 = I, M.M= I, so M.M^-1=M.M. Therefore, M^-1 = M.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the last term, I just put the brackets in a different place. $(vv^T)(vv^T)=v(v^Tv)v^T$. And what is an invertible matrix of $M$? It is a matrix $P$ (if such a matrix exists of course) such that $MP=I$. If you prove $M^2=I$ then that by definition means $M$ is the inverse of itself, because $MM=I$.

Comment: Can you also deduce it like this? M.M^-1 = I, M.M= I, so M.M^-1=M.M. Therefore, M^-1 = M?

Comment: You can't use an inverse until you proved the matrix is invertible. Once you showed that $MM=I$ you proved it is invertible and the inverse is $M$. Well, if after that you really want you can write it like you just did. But only after you showed that $M^2=I$.

Answer (score 1):

I would first show that symmetric matrices are closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Then I would show that $I$ is symmetric and $v v^T$ is symmetric since they are the non-scalar parts of the equation. To see that $M=M^{-1}$ show that $M^2=I$ and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

1

Pf that $M$ is Symmetric i.e. $M^T = M$

$$M=I-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}$$

$$\implies M^T=(I-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})^T$$

$$=(I + -2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})^T$$

$$=(I)^T + (-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})^T$$

$$=I + (-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})^T$$

$$=I + -2\frac{1}{|v|^2} (vv^T)^T$$

$$=I + -2\frac{1}{|v|^2} (v^T)^T (v)^T$$

$$=I + -2\frac{1}{|v|^2} v(v)^T$$

$$=I-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2} = M$$

Therefore, $M^T=M$. QED

2

Pf that $M^2=I$:

$$M=I-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}$$

$$\implies M^2=(I-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})(I-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})$$

$$=I^2 + 2I(-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + (2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})(2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})$$

$$=I + 2I(-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + (2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})(2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})$$

$$=I + 2I(-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + 4\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})$$

$$=I + 2(-2\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + 4\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})$$

$$=I -4 \frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + 4\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2})$$

$$=I -4 \frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + 4\frac{vv^Tvv^T}{|v|^2|v|^2}$$

$$=I -4 \frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + 4\frac{v(v^Tv)v^T}{|v|^2|v|^2}$$

$$=I -4 \frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + 4\frac{v|v|^2v^T}{|v|^2|v|^2}$$

$$=I -4 \frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}) + 4\frac{vv^T}{|v|^2}$$

$$=I$$

QED

3

Pf that $M^{-1}$ exists:

Recall that a matrix $A$ has an inverse if and only if its determinant is nonzero.

$$M^2=I$$

$$\implies \det(M^2) = \det(I)$$

$$\implies \det(M)^2 = \det(I)$$

$$\implies \det(M)^2 = 1$$

$$\implies \det(M) = \pm 1$$

$$\implies \det(M) \ne 0$$

QED

Edit: I have no idea what was going on but of course $M^{-1}$ exists a fortiori if $M^2=I$ because $M^2=I$ is equivalent to saying '$M^{-1}$ exists and $M^{-1}=M$.'

P.S. Good luck with probability or statistics next!

Comment: How do you know what course I'm taking?