# Find all integer solutions for k1 and k2, where 3/4 = k1/k2, and both values must be divisible by 64?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

I can think of k1 = 768 and k2 = 1024 as one of the solutions, but how does one generalize the problem to find all other integer values for k1 and k2 while maintaining the ratio of 3/4 and where each value must be divisible by 64?

Comment: $k1$ and $k2$ must both be $0$ mod $64$. $3$ and $64$ are relatively prime, so solutions of the form: $k1 = 192 * x$ and $k2 = 256 * x$ work

Comment: How about $k_1=3\cdot64\cdot n$?

Comment: Are you doing a master's in mathematics after graduating from a [bachelor's in engineering](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2962551/if-v-%e2%88%88-rn-is-a-nonzero-vector-and-i-%e2%88%88-rn%c3%97n-is-an-identify-matrix-prove-that)?